# Short story about a laser-soccer type sport in which a team defends against shots on goal by reflecting the laser beams

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

Does anyone recognize this story from an old sci-fi book of short stories? I'm looking for the title of both the story and the anthology, if possible.

A laser-soccer type team (reflect the light into the goal) is used where they defend against an attacking enemy by reflecting the laser shots?
The last sentence was something like:

> After reflecting, the enemy withdrew.

Answer (score 17):

This is probably "[Bullard Reflects](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46452)" by Malcolm Jameson.

In this story they are spacemen who play a sport called "Dazzle Dart" which involves reflecting light beams. They are captured by bad guys who dump them on an asteroid to hunt them down for fun.

However, the asteroid has a reflective ore (from a meteor, I think) on it, and the spacemen fashion mirrors and use their mad Dazzle Dart skillz to reflect the bad guys' beams back at them.

The story is in the classic anthology [A Treasury of Great Science Fiction](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1315) which was a mainstay of the Science Fiction Book Club in the 70s. I wouldn't be surprised if that's where you read it.

Previously answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194569/28516) from where I copied the above.

It ends as you state, with the "reflecting" "joke".

Comment: @Donna if this is the correct answer, please click the gray check mark to show that the question is answered.